# Удаленное подключение и обработка php файла

Tags: php

Есть файл на удаленном сервере, test.php, пытаюсь подкючить этот файл через

```
include 'http://www.site.ru/test.php';
```

Ошибок PHP не выдаёт, `allow_url_fopen` включен, и `allow_url_include` тоже включен.

Я в файле test.php пишу тестовую переменную `$test_file  = true;`

Пытаюсь вывести её после подключения - `null`;

Вообще, можно ли так подключать, что бы все зачитывалось как PHP содержимое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если на сайте site.ru настроена обработка PHP-файлов, вы не сможете получить таким образом исходный код. Вы получите результат выполнения файла test.php. Подключить PHP-код с удаленного сайта вы сможете, если он отдается без искажений, например, в виде txt-файла

```
include 'http://www.site.ru/test.txt';
```

PS Однако, следует иметь в виду, что это довольно опасная практика (и медленно, и не безопасно), особенно, если вы не контролируете удаленный сервер. В профессиональном коде вы почти никогда не увидите такого приема.

Comment: сейчас попробуем, момент